# The system of equations: $\begin{cases} 2x^2=4y^2+3z^2+2; \\ 13x=4y+3z+29 \end{cases}$

Tags: diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

Solve in positive integers the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
2x^2=4y^2+3z^2+2;
\\
13x=4y+3z+29
\end{cases}$$

#### My work so far:

I used [wolframalpha:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E2%3D4y%5E2%2B3z%5E2%2B2;%2013x%3D4y%2B3z%2B29) $x=3,y=1,z=2$.

Comment: [Graphically](http://www.hapshack.com/images/H9Lca.png) at least, there should not be many integer solutions, so a kind of "brute force" approach might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2x^2=4y^2+3z^2+2\tag1$$
$$13x=4y+3z+29\tag2$$

From $(1)(2)$,
$$13^2(4y^2+3z^2+2)=2(13x)^2=2(4y+3z+29)^2,$$
i.e.
$$644y^2+(-464-48z)y+489z^2-348z-1344=0$$
See this as a quadratic equation on $y$.

Since the discriminant has to be larger than or equal to $0$, we have to have
$$(-464-48z)^2-4\cdot 644(489z^2-348z-1344)\ge 0,$$
i.e.
$$\small -1.5\approx -\frac{236}{155}=\frac{2(87-49\sqrt{81})}{465}\le \frac{2(87-49\sqrt{69})}{465}\le z\le \frac{2(87+49\sqrt{69})}{465}\le \frac{2(87+49\sqrt{81})}{465}=\frac{352}{155}\approx 2.3$$
giving $$z=1,2$$

I think that you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$2x^2=4y^2+3z^2+2\tag1$$
$$13x=4y+3z+29\tag2$$
(1)
$$2x^2=4y^2+3z^2+2 \Rightarrow x>\max\{y,z\}$$
(2)
$$13x=4y+3z+29<4x+3x+29 \Rightarrow 6x<29 \Rightarrow x<5$$

(1) $z -$ even. (2) $x -$ odd. Hence $x \in \{1,3\}$. But $x>y,z\ge1$. Hence $$x=3$$